# Add parsed elements from text file to array

Tags: c

I am trying to write a code that fetches lines from a txt file and adds parsed out variables from those lines to an array. The txt file reading and the parsing works perfectly.

My text file "inventory.txt" looks like this:

```
Mars;6
Snickers;7
Bounty;2
Twix;4
MilkyWay;6
KitKat;8
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    //INITIALIZE
    char line[100];
    char *elements[100] = {};
    int i_stock[100];
    int r2 = 0;

    char item[20] = {0};
    int stock;

    //DEFINE FILE
    FILE *the_file = fopen("inventory.txt","r");

    //CHECK IF FILE EXISTS
    if(the_file == NULL) {
        perror("Inventarfehler");
        exit(1);
    }

    //SCAN LINES FOR STOCK
    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), the_file)) {
        sscanf(line, "%[a-zA-Z];%d", &item, &stock);
        
        //ADD VAR TO ARRAY
        elements[r2] = item;
        r2++;
    }
    
    printf(elements[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Whatever index of `elements` I print, it is always `KitKat`. My code keeps overwriting the variables.

`printf("%s",elements[2])` should print out `Bounty`.

Could anyone help me solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: One option is to copy the parsed strings e.g. `elements[r2] = strdup(item)`. As it stands, you are always referencing `item` whose content will ultimately be the last candy bar name you read.

Comment: Thank you @jarmod for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that all of your elements are simple references to `item` whose content will ultimately be the last candy bar name you read.

Here is one way to solve this problem, by copying each parsed string to a newly-allocated string on the heap using `strdup()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_COUNT 100

int main()
{

    //INITIALIZE
    char line[MAX_COUNT];
    char *elements[MAX_COUNT] = {};
    int i_stock[MAX_COUNT];
    int r2 = 0;

    char item[20] = {0};
    int stock;

    //DEFINE FILE
    FILE *the_file = fopen("inventory.txt", "r");

    //CHECK IF FILE EXISTS
    if (the_file == NULL)
    {
        perror("Inventarfehler");
        exit(1);
    }

    //SCAN LINES FOR STOCK
    while (r2 < MAX_COUNT && fgets(line, sizeof(line), the_file))
    {
        sscanf(line, "%[a-zA-Z];%d", item, &stock);

        //ADD VAR TO ARRAY
        elements[r2] = strdup(item);
        r2++;
    }

    printf("%s\n", elements[2]);

    // Free allocated memory
    for (int ii = 0; ii < r2; ii++)
    {
        // printf("Free elements[%d]: %s\n", ii, elements[ii]);
        free(elements[ii]);
        elements[ii] = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```